# Is it possible to use calc() inside transform:scale()?

Tags: css

I have an iframe with a banner advert in it (Amazon affiliate link) and I'd like to make the banner responsive.  In the UK Amazon don't offer a responsive banner (their US programme does).

My thought was to add this CSS to the iframe tag:

```
transform:scale(calc(100% / 728px));
```

or similar.

If I try it with unitless numbers it works.  E.g. `calc(0.1 + 0.4)` will indeed scale it to 50%.

But with the percentage and the px, no such luck.

I see on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc that the divisor when dividing must be a number, not a unit length.

Is there a cunning trick to getting this working?

Thanks!

Comment: what does mean scaling by pixel or percentage? We first need a math definition of how you want it to work with pixel and percentage

Comment: In my mind supposing my browser window was 364px wide, the browser would understand that 100% is 364px, and then it would divide by 728px.  The units should cancel out, and leave me with 0.5.  I'm sure there's a good reason why it DOESN'T work like that... but I can't think of one!

Comment: Use `100vw`, not `100%`. CSS has specific (and counter-intuitive) behaviour for `%` vs `vw`. **but that won't help in this case** because `scale()` requires a unitless quantity.

Comment: well, it doesn't work like in your mind .. you are asking the browser to do a lot alone. You will need JS here. CSS cannot help you

Comment: You shouldn't be using `transform: scale()` to resize your content.

Comment: Why not Dai?  As far as I know it's the only way to resize the contents of an iframe.

Comment: I did try `vw` first, I should have specified that.  It didn't work, so I moved on to `%`, had no luck there either so came to ask SO.

Comment: Thank you @TemaniAfif - somehow using JS literally didn't occur to me... My quick solution is about to be posted as an answer, of sorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided this isn't possible with CSS (I'd love to be proven wrong), so here's a quickly-hacked together JS solution.  Only works on initial page load, but it'd be trivial to add user-resizing support to it if desired.

```
function getContentWidth (element) {
    var styles = getComputedStyle(element)

    return element.clientWidth
      - parseFloat(styles.paddingLeft)
      - parseFloat(styles.paddingRight)
}

const scale = getContentWidth(document.getElementById('banner').parentNode) / 728;

if (scale < 1) {
    document.getElementById('banner').style.transform = 'scale(' + scale + ')';
    document.getElementById('banner').style.transformOrigin = 'left';
}
```